# Performance aspect of java.util.Property vs hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am java class and I really concern about performance. There are some methods which has Property as their input parameter and those methods are invoked several time in my execution. Will Replacing Property with Hashmap help to increase performance ? Hashmap is sufficient in my scenario.

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned with performance if you're still inexperienced with Java. You should be concerned with writing correct, working code. You won't see any difference in performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`java.util.Properties` extends `java.util.Hashtable`, so it is a kind of Hashtable.

Below, there are couple differences relevant for your case:

`java.util.Hashtable` is synchronized, but `java.util.HashMap` is not. If you have one-threaded application, HashMap will perform better than Hashtable.

`java.util.Hashtable` does not allow null keys nor values, while `java.util.HashMap` allows one null key and many null values.

Consider these differences for your project and take a decision.

Answer (score 2):

Properties is for special purposes, if HashMap is OK for your program - use it. HashMap also has better performance because Properties is based on Hashtable whose methods are synchronized